# Using Javascript or jQuery - Find node with correct attribute date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Using Javascript (preferably jQuery) I need to access the "node" where "X" date will fall within its "begin" and "end" dates.

**XML EXAMPLE:**

```
<nodes>
    <node begin="2014-01-01" end="2014-01-31">
        <info1>blah blah</info1>
        <info2>blah blah</info2>
        <info3>blah blah</info3>
    </node>
    <node begin="2014-02-01" end="2014-02-28">
        <info1>blah blah</info1>
        <info2>blah blah</info2>
        <info3>blah blah</info3>
    </node>
    <node begin="2014-03-01" end="2014-03-31">
        <info1>blah blah</info1>
        <info2>blah blah</info2>
        <info3>blah blah</info3>
    </node>
</nodes>
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.filter()` method:

```
var nodes = $(xml),
    x = new Date("...");

var matched = nodes.children().filter(function() {
    var b = new Date( this.getAttribute('begin') ),
        e = new Date( this.getAttribute('end') );
    return b <= x && x <= e;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)  and try with the below code

```
var startDate = new Date(2014,01,01)
  , endDate   = new Date(2014,01,31)
  , date  = new Date(2014, 01, 15)
  , range = moment().range(startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: Parse your XML to find the start date, end date and current date